# Android, ViewPager не перелистывает страницу

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Доброе утро, собственно вопрос в том,что после выборе элемента списка и после перелистывания на другую страницу открывается та же страница (т.е. выбрал 1, прелистнул на 2-ю стр., но открывается всё равно первая)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by homepc on 28.01.2018.
 */

public class NotePagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_NOTE_ID =
            "note_id";

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private List<Note> mNotes;

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID noteId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, NotePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTE_ID, noteId);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_pager);

        UUID noteId = (UUID) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_NOTE_ID);

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.note_view_pager);

        mNotes = NoteLab.get(this).getNotes();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Note note = mNotes.get(position);
                return NoteFragment.newInstnce(note.getId());
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mNotes.size();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mNotes.size(); i++ ){
            if (mNotes.get(i).getId().equals(noteId)){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    }
```